# Cannot read property “send” of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a Karuta trade application bot and it keeps saying `Cannot read property “send” of undefined`.

Everytime I try to figure out the problem it gets worse and worse.

Can someone please help me to figure out this problem thats breaking my application process?

It fails when it trys to send to a channel called test

Code:

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: `apply`,
    /**
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args 
     */
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        const questions = [
            "Would you like to advertise your Karuta Card Trades?",
            "Cards FS:",
            "Cards FB:"
        ]
        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        
        const appStart = await message.author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
        const channel = appStart.channel

        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        
        collector.on("collect", () => {
            if(collectCounter < questions.length) {
                channel.send(questions[collectCounter++])
            } else {
                channel.send('Your application has been submitted!')
                collector.stop("fulfilled");
            }
        });
        const APPS_CHANNEL_ID = '822605997356875777'
        const appsChannel = await client.channels.fetch(APPS_CHANNEL_ID)
        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if(reason == 'fulfilled') {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected.map((msg) => {
                    return `${index++}) ${questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`;
                })
                .join('\n\n')
                appsChannel.send(
                    new MessageEmbed()
                        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
                        )
                        .setTitle('New Application')
                        .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                        .setColor('RED')
                        .setTimestamp()
                )
                throw new Error('TOKEN_MISSING');
            }
        });
    },
    }
```

Error:

```css
(node:3435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/mahdiabbas/Documents/Karuta Trade/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/mahdiabbas/Documents/Karuta Trade/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:97:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (/Users/mahdiabbas/Documents/Karuta Trade/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ChannelManager.fetch (/Users/mahdiabbas/Documents/Karuta Trade/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/ChannelManager.js:91:18)
    at async Object.execute (/Users/mahdiabbas/Documents/Karuta Trade/commands/tradead.js:35:29)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3435) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Index.js:

````css
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client()
const client = new Discord.Client()
const prefix = '-';

const queue = new Map();
const fs = require('fs');
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));



for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is online.`)
  bot.user.setStatus(`dnd`)
  bot.user.setActivity({
    type: `WATCHING`,
    name: `Out For Subaru`,
  })
})


bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command = bot.commands.get(commandName) || bot.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
  try {
    command.execute(client, message, args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});```
````

Comment: Which is the four `.send()` methods is the one that is failing.

Comment: can you include the full error? there's 4 places where `.send()` is called so we don't know which one it  is

Comment: With respect, when you get an error message, do some basic troubleshootingl. Which line of code threw the message? Which line called that line? In this case, you need to figure out **which line** of your program threw the error. You have `.author.send()`, `.channel.send()`, and `.appsChannel.send()`. Your error message means one of those things `author`, `channel` or `appsChannel` is `null`. But which one? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `client.channels.cache.get('822605997356875777')` returns `undefined`. This likely means the channel wasn't cached. You can use [`ChannelManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) to fetch the channel.

You are also creating an additional `Client` object (which isn't logged in) and passing it to the `execute` function. You don't need it. Remove `const client = new Discord.Client()` from `index.js`.

And update the `command.execute` call to only send `message` and `args`.

```js
command.execute(message, args)
```

You can get the `client` object from `message` in the `execute` function.

```js
async execute(message, args) {
  const { client } = message
  // ...

  const APPS_CHANNEL_ID = '822605997356875777'
  const appsChannel = await client.channels.fetch(APPS_CHANNEL_ID)
  // ...
}
```

Note that you'll have to update all commands' `execute` functions since they'll only receive `message` and `args`.

Comment: I added it in index.js

Comment: @Outrage Can you add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: @Outrage Can you also add an **Edit** section to your question and add the updated code?

Comment: @Outrage Can you add the `index.js` code to the question?

Comment: I'll do that, but I will remove the token